# Creating custom arc shapes (multiple bumps)

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginner at 3D modelling and currently stuck on modelling an arc for a furniture piece i'm working on. As per the image below, I thought this would be a relatively easy piece to model but of the methods i've try, none of them seem to be working!  [image: Arc Outline]

[image: Explorations]
The closest I've gotten is first creating a rectangle, giving it some loop cuts and performing the warp function. But when I try to create the additional bumps, I'm assuming the lack of vertexes made it impossible to smooth out those sections. Does anyone know what a possible way of creating an arc like the one I attached may be? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, start with a cylinder, delete half of it end extrude sides, then you have a perfect arct. then you can extrude the bump where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use NURBS Curve to model the lower part
   [image]
2. Still in Edit Mode add another NURBS curve and model the upper part or the 180° arc
3. Convert both to mesh, close at the bottom with edges and fill
4. Extrude these bottom edges
5. Y-Extrude the whole model

Comment: Thanks for this! Tried it out and it works perfectly! A question about UV unwrapping afterwards.. would creating the arc through this method create problems when I add a texture? I know when i tried to add a subdivide modified, Blende was lagging a lot.. not sure if that will affect UV unwrapping in the future!

Comment: Subdivide modifier mau cause problems if you filled with an n-gon. Try grid fill or/and retopologize. Use Remesh modifier.